# Find out which columns must be specified in insert-statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, default-value

Sometimes when inserting data in a table with many columns it could be useful to know which columns must be specified if the insert-statement shouldn't fail.

I wrote this query to find out which columns are not nullable, identity, computed, timestamp and have no default value.

```
select  *
from    sys.columns
where   object_id = object_id('<table>') and
        is_nullable = 0 and
        is_identity = 0 and
        is_computed = 0 and
        default_object_id = 0 and
        type_name(system_type_id) <> 'timestamp'
```

Are there any other properties that should be included in this check?

Comment: You could look at column level permission too...

Comment: @gbn How would I do that? Feel free to add an answer.

Comment: Do NewID values show up as `is_identity`?

Comment: @JNK Isn't that a default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BOL documentation for the [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) grammar has this to say about `column_list`

> If a column is not in `column_list`, the Database Engine must be able to
>   provide a value based on the definition of the column; otherwise, the
>   row cannot be loaded. The Database Engine automatically provides a
>   value for the column if the column:
>
> - Has an `IDENTITY` property. The next incremental identity value is used.
> - Has a default. The default value for the column is used.
> - Has a `timestamp` data type. The current `timestamp` value is used.
> - Is nullable. A null value is used.
> - Is a computed column. The calculated value is used.

It looks as though your query covers all these cases to me.